# SBCL development on Windows, including CFFI

Tags: windows, automation, common-lisp

I have been asked to automate the operation of a Windows (WinForms) application, performing some fairly complicated statistical analysis along the way.

My first thought was the usual suspects: .NET, C# and White or AutoItX.

Then it occured to me that I could try an alternative stack: SBCL, CFFI, and AutoItX.  That way, I could write in a language I like (Common Lisp), using my native Linux development tools via SLIME and Swank.

Hence my question: is there some reason I *shouldn't* try this?  I'm a Common Lisp newbie, and have essentially zero experience in CL FFI or SBCL on Windows.  The learning curve isn't a problem, though.  I'm worried that someone may have tried something like this in the past and discovered insurmountable issues.  My list of concerns includes:

- stability / completeness of CFFI on SBCL on Windows
- getting SLIME on Linux talking to SBCL running on a Windows box

Any experience, advice or warnings on any aspect of my proposed stack would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question on an SBCL list, but having said "wrong place" it's an interesting question. Off-hand I don't see any particular difficulties: SWANK is a protocol, so you're fine there, and I didn't have major problems with SBCL on Windows (but I did nothing fancy, and it was years ago).

Answer (score 5):

This is a little late, but as of about 2 months ago (05/2018) I found this project called Portacle which bundles SBCL, Emacs, Quicklisp, and more into a single package for Windows 10. All you have to do is double click the `portacle.exe` file and you have a full blown Common Lisp IDE to work with.

See https://portacle.github.io/ and https://github.com/portacle/portacle

Answer (score 3):

Here is half of an answer.

Clozure Common Lisp (CCL) is the "best" Common Lisp implementation for windows. It works great with Emacs/SLIME. I haven't had any issues but I don't get to use Lisp beyond tinkering. Not sure about CFFI.

To save you a bit of searching....
On my windows XP box I had to add CCL to the path. When you set the inferior-lisp-program it does not assume an absolute path.

Start -> right click "My computer" -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> click "PATH" -> edit -> add path to CCL into the ";" separated list.

Then add this to .emacs:

```
(set-language-environment "utf-8") ;for clozure cl
(setq inferior-lisp-program "wx86cl.exe -K utf-8") ;clozure cl
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/slime/") ; your SLIME directory
(require 'slime)
(setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```